# How do I edit multiple strings inside a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I'm currently working with a data structure that uses a dictionary where the value for each key is a list. For the sake of the question, I've simplified my structure into an easy-to-understand example.

Using a for loop, how would I loop through the values of each list and change them based on a certain character in each string? This is what I have so far:

```
test_dict = {"key1": ["value1", "value2"], "key2": ["value3", "value4"]}

for key in test_dict:
    for value in test_dict[key]:
        if "v" in value:
            test_dict["key1"][value.index(value)] = value.replace("v", "")
```

Output:

```
{'key1': ['alue4', 'value2'], 'key2': ['value3', 'value4']}
```

The for loop is only returning value 1 edited, which - for some reason - got changed to value 4. How do I edit the loop to remove the letter v in all the values, and keep them all in the right place?

Edit: Thank you for all the comments regarding the typo for "key1" instead of "key." I must have been trying to test the step-by-step functionality and forgot to change it back to "key."

Comment: Typo.  Your last statement should be `test_dict[key]`, not `test_dict["key1"]`.  Thus, while reading through the other keys, you're forcing your edit into "key1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest dict comprehension and list comprehension:

```py
test_dict = {"key1": ["value1", "value2"], "key2": ["value3", "value4"]}

output = {k: [v[1:] for v in lst] for k, lst in test_dict.items()}
print(output) # {'key1': ['alue1', 'alue2'], 'key2': ['alue3', 'alue4']}
```

I've used `v[1:]` to remove the first character, but you can use your original code `v.replace('v', '')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clarify the types:

```py
from typing import *
test_dict: Dict[str, List[str]]
key: str
value: str
```

And when you use `value.index(value)`, you are calling `str.index(self)` and it always returns 0. You also used `test_dict["key1"]` instead of the supposed `test_dict[key]`

Final code:

```py
test_dict = {"key1": ["value1", "value2"], "key2": ["value3", "value4"]}

for key in test_dict:
    for i in range(len(test_dict[key])): # better in case there are multiple same elements
        if "v" in test_dict[key][i]:
            test_dict[key][i] = test_dict[key][i].replace("v", "")
```

I looped over the indexes because there may be multiple equal/same elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

> The for loop is only returning value 1 edited, which - for some reason - got changed to value 4.

That's because you looped through the whole dict only replacing `test_dict["key1"][0]` each time by the last value iterated.

To be more specific let's eval your code and print the result of each iteration as well as the index of the value:

```
test_dict = {"key1": ["value1", "value2"], "key2": ["value3", "value4"]}

for key in test_dict:
    for value in test_dict[key]:
        if "v" in value:
            test_dict["key1"][value.index(value)] = value.replace("v", "")
            print(test_dict)
            print(value.index(value))
```

Output is:

```
{'key1': ['alue1', 'value2'], 'key2': ['value3', 'value4']}
0
{'key1': ['alue2', 'value2'], 'key2': ['value3', 'value4']}
0
{'key1': ['alue3', 'value2'], 'key2': ['value3', 'value4']}
0
{'key1': ['alue4', 'value2'], 'key2': ['value3', 'value4']}
0
```

As you can see you only change `test_dict["key1"][0]` for each iteration.

As for the answer here's how I'd do to be as simple and readable as possible:

```
for k, v in test_dict.items():
     test_dict[k] = [value.replace("v", "") for value in v]
```

Comment: ...having to admit, this is also a good way to achieve the goal.